# Fatal error when setting UIImageView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

Hello i have a UIImageview and trying to set the image which was previously saved in a NSArray and then the NSArray is saved into an NSMutableDictionary. Here is the error and the code. Any help appreciated.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString _isSymbolImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100e14318'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                       NSMutableArray *allKeys = [[appDelegate.localDataForIngestAndErrorVideos allKeys] mutableCopy];
                     
                       for (NSString *key in allKeys) {
                          NSArray *object = (NSArray*)[appDelegate.localDataForIngestAndErrorVideos  objectForKey:key];
                           NSLog(@"id object ingest: %@",[object objectAtIndex:0]);
                           if ( [cell.Model.ContentItem.videoUploadStatus isEqualToString:@"ingest"])
                           {
                          
                               cell.Model.ContentItem.mediaVideoUriHls = (NSURL*)[object objectAtIndex:2];
                               UIImage *tempImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
                               tempImage = [object objectAtIndex:1];
                               [cell.mediaImageView setImage:tempImage];  <=== here crashes
                           }
}
```

Comment: `[object objectAtIndex:1];` is not a `UIImage`, it's a `NSString`. Could you print `object`.

Comment: You were right it wasnt a UIImage it was an NSString. If you want put an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `[__NSCFConstantString _isSymbolImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` is saying this:
Let's translate first: `__NSCFConstantString` is a inner (optimized) class for `NSString`, so just consider it as `NSString`
So you have `NSString` instance and you try to call `_isSymbolImage` method on it. That method is hidden, it's an under the hood call from iOS SDK.
But that method doesn't exists on `NSString`, it doesn't know it, hence the error you are getting.

Seeing the crash line:

```
[cell.mediaImageView setImage:tempImage];
```

The inner method called makes sense, you are treating `tempImage` as it were an `UIImage`.

So `[object objectAtIndex:1]` is a `NSString` not a `UIImage`.

Now, I'd suggest to use custom model for your `NSDictionary` `appDelegate.localDataForIngestAndErrorVideos`. It's better than handling `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` without knowing what's inside it each time.
You could also add to it methods/compute properties like `-(NSURL)ingestURL`, etc to make your code easier and more readable.

Side note:

```
UIImage *tempImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
tempImage = [object objectAtIndex:1];
```

The alloc/init is useless, since you are setting the value. You are doing an alloc/init for nothing, since you are ignoring it just after.